# How to solve сannot read property 'databaseURL' of null in Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a table titled 'bestOffers' in Cloud Firestore
I am using a function that calls when a document is added to a table.

The event settings are like this:
Event type: create
The path to the document: bestOffers/{id}

Function:
[image]

And when I run the function, I get a cannot read property 'databaseURL' of null error

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

admin.initializeApp()

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('bestOffers/{id}').onWrite(async (change, context) => {
 

})
```

Tracing:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'databaseURL' of null
    at resourceGetter (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/database.js:92:54)
    at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:102:13)
    at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:151:20)
    at Promise.resolve.then (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:198:28)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: Hi, please share the **entire** code of your Cloud Functions (and please paste the code as text, not as an image)

Comment: Also, can you clarify which database you are using: you mention Cloud Firestore but your Cloud Function is triggered by the Realtime Database.

Comment: I am using clound firestore and trigger clound firestore when creating a document

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the signature of the handler function that is passed to [`onWrite`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_database_.refbuilder#onwrite). It has two parameters: a `Change<DataSnapshot>` and an `EventContext`.

You declare your Cloud Function with:

```
...onWrite(async () => {...});
```

You should do as follows:

```
.onWrite(async (change, context) => {
  const beforeData = change.before.val(); // data before the write
  const afterData = change.after.val(); // data after the write
});
```

and, then, use the `change` object to get the data stored at the node that triggered the Cloud Function.

Comment: Yes, I do not need it, I need to make a request for the change to another server.
Unfortunately, adding parameters did not help solve the problem

Comment: The only way for us to help you is that you share the **entire** code of your Cloud Function as well as all the debugging details. Without that we cannot find the problem.

Comment: You didn’t add the code of the Cloud Function... what is **inside** `onWrite()`?